# How can I insert paragraphs from WordProcessingDocument into active document in Word Add In using Open Xml SDK?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk, office-addins

I am working on creating an Office 2013 Add In for Microsoft Word. I need to take paragraphs from multiple .Docx files and insert them at the current cursor position onto the active document. The paragraphs will also include `Content Controls`.

I have seen approaches on internet using - `altChunk` but that is not possible here, because that processes the document when it is saved and reopened, where as I need to insert onto the active document as the user performs certain action.

The second approach is using `DocumentBuilder` class from `Power Tools for Open XML`, but that provides a function like following, which just saves the document assembled from multiple sources, where as I need to insert the sources onto the cursor position in active document.

```
List<Source> sources = new List<Source>();
    sources.Add(new Source(part1, 0, 12, true));
    sources.Add(new Source(part1, 49, true));
    DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources, "Test2.docx");
```

Please suggest, if anybody has any approach that can accomplish the task I am trying to do efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to deal with the same issue, and the only solution that worked was to use Range.InsertXML MS Word API.

Regards,

Michael